# I'm successfully exporting my console output to a file. I need to stop it and then print some data on console in java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, selenium, java-io

I'm successfully exporting my console output to a file. I now need to end this procedure so that the remaining data can be printed on the console. At the moment, all of the printed statements are being exported to a file.

```
try {
        PrintStream myconsole = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\one\\Chase-"+formattedDate+".txt"));
        System.setOut(myconsole);
        myconsole.print(sb);
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fx) {
        System.out.println(fx);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `System.setOut(System.out)`?

Comment: Yes i tried it but it is not giving any good results. I even tried myconsole.close() and it does not print data in file and it doesn't also print on console. For console, i need it at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to capture the original console before you change it:

```
PrintStream prevConsole = System.out;
```

After calling `System.setOut(myconsole);` you can use `System.out.print / println` in place of `myconsole.print / println`.

Afterwards revert to the original console with:

```
System.setOut(prevConsole);
```

Then don't forget to use `myconsole.close()` to close your file in appropriate place.